# IF-Else One-Line Comprehension

Tags: python, data-analysis

**Here is the example of my code:**

It returns `True` if 3 is followed by 3, else returns `False`
Below code is working like a charm

```
def has_33(nums):
    for i in range(len(nums)-1):
        if (nums[i] ==3) and (nums[i+1] ==3):
            return True
    return False
has_33([1, 3, 3])
```

Below code is working as well:

```
def has_33(nums):
    return any([(nums[i] ==3) and (nums[i+1] ==3) for i in range(len(nums)-1)])
```

**When I try to make one-line comprehension of this code, it doesn't work:**

```
def has_33(nums):
    return True if (nums[i] ==3) and (nums[i+1] ==3) else False for i in range(len(nums)-1)

has_33([1, 3, 3])
```

I am just curious to know why it doesn't work and how to fix it.

Comment: do you wish to return multiple values or single value? also the value you are calling 'list comprehension' in the 3rd code snippet will throw an error. It should be enclosed in square brackets

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are trying to use list comprehension then following code works flawlessly:

```
def has_33(nums):
    return   any([True if (nums[i] ==3) and (nums[i+1] ==3) else False  for i in range(len(nums)-1) ])
print(has_33([1, 3, 3]))
```

Comment: Good response, but the ternary operator is redondant in your code, (nums[i] ==3) and (nums[i+1] ==3) alreay returns a boolean

Comment: Right. I see that.

Answer (score 4):

un-winding list comprehension code,

```
def has_33(nums):
    for i in range(len(nums) - 1):
        if (nums[i] == 3) and (nums[i+1] == 3):
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

the loop will return after first iteration.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is your code return false during the first iteration even if there will be a match after.
There is the any() inline function to do what you want. https://docs.python.org/fr/3/library/functions.html#any

```
def has_33(nums):
    return any(num[i]==3 and num[i+1]==3 for i in range(len(nums) - 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I went to use List Comprehension like that:

```
def has_33(nums):
    return [(True if (nums[i] ==3) and (nums[i+1] ==3) else False) for i in range(len(nums)-1)]
```

It returned on your example:
`[False, True]`
So just check if "True" exists in your list:

```
def has_33(nums):
    return True in [(True if (nums[i] ==3) and (nums[i+1] ==3) else False) for i in range(len(nums)-1)]
```

This will returns `True`/`False` whether a `3` is followed by a `3` or not.